# phpMailer: Passing more than one variable to an email template

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to pass more than one variable to the email template using the script below:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$email = 'versace@versace.it';

$data['fname'] = $_POST['c_fname'];
$data['lname'] = $_POST['c_lname'];

$mail->setFrom('armani@armani.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addReplyTo('armani@armani.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addAddress($email, 'John Doe');

$mail->Subject = 'Your confirmation';
$mail -> msgHTML(file_get_contents('temp.php',$data), dirname(__FILE__));
$mail->AltBody = 'Thank you for contacting us';

if (!$mail->send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
redirect('index.php');
}
```

This is ther error message:
**Mailer Error: Message body empty**

Wha I am doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure that temp.php is returning data? Try this and let us know if it works: $mail->msgHTML("a test string");

Comment: Hi, temp.php is returnig data.

Comment: It seems that you think `file_get_contents` is going to parse your PHP file and extract the `$data` array into variables for that file. `file_get_contents` does not work that way, and the second argument for the function should be a boolean which dictates whether the include path should be used when finding a file.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your reply. How does file_get_contents works exactly. Do you maybe have an example?

Comment: It simply returns the contents of the file, so it'll look the same as in a text editor with `<?php` and `?>` tags and `$variables` present. [See the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) for more info

Comment: what about removing the spaces around the arrow on $mail -> msgHTML? ;)

Answer (score 1):

The message body is empty because [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) is returning null. You're passing it an array as the second parameter (`$use_include_path`) when a boolean is required so it throws a warning and returns null.

It appears what you're trying to do is extract the `$data` array in your question into variables and then have `temp.php` parsed through PHP with those variables. You cannot do this using `file_get_contents` because it simply returns the contents of the file and does not parse any PHP code within the file. You need to use output buffering, include the file and then assign the output to a variable:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$email = 'versace@versace.it';

$data[ 'fname' ] = $_POST[ 'c_fname' ];
$data[ 'lname' ] = $_POST[ 'c_lname' ];

$mail->setFrom( 'armani@armani.com', 'First Last' );
$mail->addReplyTo( 'armani@armani.com', 'First Last' );
$mail->addAddress( $email, 'John Doe' );

$mail->Subject = 'Your confirmation';
$mail->msgHTML( renderTemplate( 'temp.php', $data ), dirname( __FILE__ ) );
$mail->AltBody = 'Thank you for contacting us';

if ( ! $mail->send() ) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    redirect( 'index.php' );
}

function renderTemplate( $file, $data ) {
    if ( ! file_exists( $file ) ) {
        trigger_error( 'renderTemplate: file does not exist' );
        exit;
    }

    extract( $data );

    ob_start();

    include($file);

    $content = ob_get_clean();

    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is because you are not setting the body:

This may be because the file does not return data.

Alternate methhod to do the same would be to use the following:

`$mail->Body`

[Source](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

**Edit**: Also use

> $mail->isHTML(true); // To Set email format to HTML

[Source](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: actually msgHTML is a valid function: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/40a0a1b160d91e9950e75b3e810e8e8124663183/examples/mail.phps

Comment: @nowhere which would mean that the file returned nothing.